# ContentProvider and Binder IPC

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-binder

i have a doubt regarding content provider.. we know binder cant transfer large amount of data (~>3MB) but even content provider uses binder IPC right which may involve >3 MB transfer?
or content provider directly read database within caller process memory space and doesn't involve IPC ?

Please correct my understanding.

Comment: ContentProvider has Binders restrictions and cannot transfer data bigger than default Binders transaction size

Comment: Thanks pskink for your replay , As we know db total data can be more than default binder transaction size so when i get cursor after query using contentresolver .. cursor points to whole data in client process space ? or it just point to one record in different process space and take IPC call per record in db ? Please correct me

Comment: unfortunatelly the whole CursorWindow is copied from ContentProvider's process to client's one, bur maybe android:multiprocess could help

Comment: As I wrote in the separate answer, the CursorWindow is *not* copied but passed as a piece of shared memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the lowest level, content providers use CursorWindows, which are based on shared memory (ashmem).

Looking at the AOSP source file `frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/CursorWindow.cpp`, the lowest level C++ code does not seem to impose any restrictions on the shared memory size, other than those inherited from the system-level ashmem and mmap services.

The next code layer, `frameworks/base/core/jni/android_database_CursorWindow.cpp`, doesn't seem to impose any limits to the cursor window size either.

The Java code, `frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/CursorWindow.java`, reads the buffer size from the Android frameworks internal configuration value `config_cursorWindowSize`, which at least in KitKat seems to be 2048 by default.  Hence, in KitKat the maximum CursorWindow size is 2 Mb if you use the normal Java interfaces.  However, if you use the `androidfw/CursorWindow.h` directly from C++, using the AOSP headers, then you can use larger CursorWindows.  (Note that just using the NDK is not enough, since the CursorWindow is not part of the NDK API.)

Comment: I'm new to android. Is there any particular reason why `CursorWindow` uses ashmem instead of heap? How come it is related to SQLite DB in terms of ashmem?